# Magento 2 Website Speed is Too Slow

Tags: magento2, pagespeed, speedoptimization

I'm using magento on VPS server 4GB RAM. but my site speed is much much slow.. It takes almost 2 minutes to load

can you plz advice 
my website URL is **https://muzikhausberlin.de/**

i'm using putty shell it also take much time

Comment: You need to optimize your site. Please visit this link https://servebolt.com/articles/speed-up-magento-2-in-7-easy-steps/ and https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-performance-optimization/

Answer (score 1):

> **Here Some Links For `Speed up` or the `Performance Optimization` :-**

[Speed up Magento 2 in 7 easy steps](https://servebolt.com/articles/speed-up-magento-2-in-7-easy-steps/)

[Magento 2 Performance Optimization](https://www.mageplaza.com/blog/magento-2-performance-optimization/)

[Speed up Magento - The Ultimate Guide (Updated 2019)](https://www.goivvy.com/blog/speed-up-magento)

Comment: how i can check if problem by host?

Answer (score 1):

Your going to need more resource.

Will depend on max concurrent connections but you should be looking at around 10 GB RAM for 5-10 concurrent connections with background processes.

Magento 2 is resource intensive.

memory_limit should be 756 MB

https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3/.htaccess#L67

Comment: how i can check if problem by host?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Switch your website to **production mode**
> 2. **Minify** your HTML, CSS and js files.
> 3. **Merge** your CSS and JS files.
> 4. **Optmize** your images.
> 5. Enable **Gzip** Compression.
> 6. Ensure if Magento **Full Page Cache** is enabled. Can install and configure varnish to speed up the site

You can too use profiler to check files consuming more time. Check and ensure to load them in lesser time.

```
php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable html

php bin/magento dev:profiler:enable csvfile
```

Comment: how i can check if problem by host?

Comment: Since VPS has 4GB of RAM it can not be as slow as we are experiencing now. See if the cache is enabled in your site.

Answer (score 0):

According to GTmetrix - https://gtmetrix.com/reports/muzikhausberlin.de/KoDmqGWz, your website needs serious performance optimization.
You need to:

- optimize plugins and themes using GZIP compression;
- don't forget about caching, it improves performance by retaining frequently used information so when the visitor comes back, their browser doesn’t have to reload the entire page every time;
- delete identical content to reduce number of requests;
- optimize images: you can use extensions ( [Apptrian](https://www.apptrian.com/image-optimizer-for-magento) or [Potatocommerce](https://potatocommerce.com/image-optimizer-magento-2.html)); command-line tools (Gifsicle, Jpegtran, or OptiPNG);
- minify JavaScript files to speed up the page load;
- review code to find buggy one. Most often this issue arises after the integration of poor quality third-party extensions or custom features added by inexperienced Magento developers.
  If you have questions, feel free to [ask](https://whidegroup.com/services/magento-performance-optimization/).